# How to send & character in telegram bot?

Tags: php, string, telegram-bot

I need to send URL of the website in telegram message via PHP.
I use this code

```
    public function sendMessage($userid, $text)
        {
            try {
                $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $this->token . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $userid . '&text=' . $text;
                file_get_contents($url);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log("\n sendMessage: " . $e->getMessage(), 3, 'log.txt');
            }
        }
$urlSearch = 'https://www.travelenter.com/Train?TrainArrivals=' . $destinateCode . '&TrainArrivalDates=' . $DateToday . '&TrainDepartures=' . $sourceCode . '&TrainDepartureDates=' . $DateToday . '&TrainIsOneWays=False&TrainPassengers=1&TrainTicketTypes=0&RNames=3&CheckCompartments=false&isoneways=false';
sendMessage($userid, $urlSearch);
```

After sending message a section of URL deleted.I check and found that telegram send URL to `&` character and delete to end of URL.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try to use syntax like this `"https://www.travelenter.com/Train?TrainArrivals={$destinateCode}&TrainArrivalDates={$DateToday}"..`. Or if it won't work, try to use some php functions like `rawurlencode or urlencode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

```
$urlSearch = "hello&world";
$urlSearch = urlencode($urlSearch);
sendMessage($userid, $urlSearch);
```